# Facebook share dialog not showing from fragment

Tags: android, facebook, dialog

I'm using the following code to share a url+image on facebook:

```
public void simpleShare(String toShare, Uri uriImage) {
        Log.d(TAG,"simpleShare, toShare: " + toShare + ", uri: " + uriImage);
        ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(getActivity());

        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setImageUrl(uriImage)
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(toShare))
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);

    }
```

This code is inside a class that extends DialogFragment. The facebook dialog is showing correctly if called from an Activity, but it's not working if called from a Fragment. This is happening only on Android 4, not on Android 5 (i.e. on Android 5 is working fine even from the fragment). Any idea why is it happening?
I can assure that the call from activity or fragment are exact the same, I used the log to compare them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try with the code:
instead of getActivity use the class, and remove the imageurl parse into contentur first

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(url))
                .setQuote(msg)
                .build();

        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
            ShareDialog.show(activity, content);
            result.success("success");
        }
```

the new facebook SDK change some ways to make the dialog share run, and they dont give us many documentation about and how